# PHP and Child Processes

Tags: php, multithreading

So I've been developing PHP for a bit now and have been attempting to troubleshoot why exec with a redirection of standard IO is still hanging the main thread.

```
exec(escapeshellcmd("php ".getcwd()."/orderProcessing.php" . " " . $Prepared . " " . escapeshellarg(35). "> /dev/null 2>&1 &"));
```

The code provided is what I've been trialing with, and I can't seem to get it to not hang until the other script completes. The reason I am doing this is in this paticular case, processing an order can take upto 30 seconds, and I don't want the user on the frontend to wait for that.

Can I only spawn child processes with php-fpm?

Is there something I have misconfigured?

Am I just misunderstanding how child processes work?

Setup is:
Centos 7 with Apache HTTPD and PHP 8.1.11

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `> /dev/null 2>&1 &` seems ok. Maybe you missing a space here `escapeshellarg(35). ">`, test with `escapeshellarg(35). " >`.   And i thing you should use `>>` instead.

Comment: May the Problem is elsewhere, so may test this simple cmd first: `sleep 10 >> /dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: Hello!

When I try space, no change
When I try >> no change
the Sleep 10 worked though so weird, this led me to try removing the php in from the exec (just to try) and this threw me a 126 return code.

Comment: So it seems that the problem is elsewhere and can not help you more here. Hopefully you find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in PHP. With proc_open() function, you can send command without wait another process. With handle opened stream, you can catch process status and check it consistently. For example:

```php
$max = 5;
$streams = [];
$command = 'php ' . __DIR__ . '/../../process runSomeProcessCommand';

while (true) {
echo 'Working :' . count($streams) . "\n";

for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {

if (!isset($streams[$i])) {
$descriptor = [
0 => ['pipe', 'r'],
1 => ['pipe', 'w'],
2 => ['pipe', 'w']
];

echo "proc opened $i \n";
$streams[$i]['proc'] = proc_open($command . ":$i", $descriptor, $pipes);
$streams[$i]['pipes'] = $pipes;
$streams[$i]['ttl'] = time();

usleep(200000);
} else {

    $info = proc_get_status($streams[$i]['proc']);
    if ($info['running'] === false) {
        echo "Finished $i . TTL: (" . (time() - $streams[$i]['ttl']) . " sec.).Response:  " . stream_get_contents($streams[$i]['pipes'][1]) . " \n";
        fclose($streams[$i]['pipes'][1]);

        if ($error = stream_get_contents($streams[$i]['pipes'][2])) {
            echo "Error for $i. Error: $error " . PHP_EOL;
            fclose($streams[$i]['pipes'][2]);
        }

        proc_close($streams[$i]['proc']);
        unset($streams[$i]);
    } else {
        echo "Running process (PID {$info['pid']}) - $i: \n";
    }
    # $return_value = proc_close($streams[$i]);
}
}

sleep(3);
}
```

There are 5 threads in same time which are doesn't wait one another.

Comment: Hi! That worked perfectly! I'm a little confused about how the whole descriptors thing works but it works like a charm! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: here you are. You may look about it proc_open() php documentation. It is related with php streams

Comment: Also, I can give information, there are procedures inside loop. But firstly, all commands send without receive response. After it, loop works consistently and checks them accordingly.

Comment: For pipe procedures, you can see http://www.hackingwithphp.com/16/1/9/piping-between-processes